# Django /static/ files not found, 404 error

Tags: python, django, django-4.1

I have a problem with loading static files. It wont load images on my page at all.
When i look for the address it says /apps/assets/img..... But it should be /static/assets/img like on the home page and login page. (/apps/ is my view name but i don't get it why it loads it like that..(
All apps are in my installed apps directory,
DIRS in templates is configured,
i have 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
tried running collectstatic,
rerunning the server,

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"] ,
STATIC_URL = '/static/' ,
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'static_root'
```

Comment: Could you add your url files ? After running collectstatic, have you something in the configured dir ? Your variable STATIC_ROOT is ok ? What is the VENV_PATH ? Have you set the STATICFILES_FINDERS variable ?

Comment: Show your template with static file references and urls.py. Also it might help if you show folder structure and `collectstatic` output.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to handle static files in Django:

1. Create a (static) folder in the Root Directory of the Project
2. Paste Your Static Files Folder in (static(js,CSS,images...etc)
3. Now Do Setting in
   **setting.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static') 
]
```

4. add `{% load static %}` tag on top of html page
5. Now use `{% static 'assets/image.jpg' %}` tag in HTML File for calling static files
6. Done

Comment: He wrote `tried running collectstatic`, so your assumption is not correct.

Comment: answer updated check it.

Answer (score -1):

Set `DEBUG` value to `True` in `settings.py`. Remember that `DEBUG` value should be almost ALWAYS set to `False` in production, so read about overriding settings via additional file (`settings_local.py` and et cetera).